# Blazor Mudblazor form validation not Firing with multiple level child components

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I am using Blazor Mudblazor **v6.17.0**  and I have a component called **CustomerComponent**

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
    <div class="col-4 mb-3">
        <MudAutocomplete id="name" For="@(() => Customer.Name)" T="string" Label="Name:" @bind-Value="Customer.Name" SearchFunc="@SearchCustomer" Margin="Margin.Dense" Dense="true" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />
    </div>
</div>


@code {
    [Parameter] public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public IEnumerable<string> CustomerList { get; set; }
   
    private Task<IEnumerable<string>> SearchCustomer(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            Customer.Name = "";
            return Task.FromResult(CustomerList);
        }
        var filteredList = CustomerList.Where(x => x.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        return Task.FromResult(filteredList);
    }
```

and a Component that consumes this component called **CustomerTemplateComponent**

```
 <EditForm Model="@Template" OnValidSubmit="SaveEvent">
       <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
       <br />
       <div class="row" style="padding-top: 6px;">
           <div class="col-12">
               <MudTextField id="TemplateName" For="@(() => Template.TemplateName)" @bind-Value="Template.TemplateName" 
                             Label="Template Name:" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Margin="Margin.Dense"></MudTextField>
           </div>
       </div>
       <CustomerComponent  Currencies="@Currencies" CustomerList="@CustomerList" 
                            Customer="@Template.Customer"
                            "/>
       
       <div class="row" style="padding-top:8px;">
           <div class="col-12 text-end mb-3">
               <button class="btn btn-primary" disabled="@Processing" id="Save-Button">Save</button>
               <div type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="CancelEvent" id="Cancel-Button">Cancel</div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </EditForm>
}
@code {
    [Parameter] public bool Processing { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Template Template { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback CancelEvent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback SaveEvent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public IEnumerable<string> CustomerList { get; set; }

}
```

and this component is used like follows

and this is used here

```
<MudPaper Elevation="10">
    <MudGrid Class="d-flex align-content-center justify-center flex-grow-1 gap-4" Style="padding:10px;">
        <CustomerTemplateComponent CancelEvent="@Cancel" CustomerList="@Customers" 
                             SaveEvent="@Save" Processing="@Processing" Customer="@_customer" />
    </MudGrid>
</MudPaper> 



private async Task Save()
    {
        Processing = true;

        try
        {
            await _templateService.SaveAsync(_template);
            ToastService.ShowSuccess("Template Updated.");
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/tradetemplates");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex, "Error saving templates.");
            ToastService.ShowError(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Processing = false;
        }
    }

here are the classes


public class Template 
    {
        public string TemplateName { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Customer 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The Issue I have is when the button is clicked the form is not validated and the api is called with an invalid mode, the base component does not bind either. Should i be using cascading parameters or something else when going two levels deep with parameters? Or is there a different error, because when I consume the Base component from a top level form it works fine.

Working sample can be found https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GEGSkxGrGBqyVXZR

Comment: Can you share your Template class and your Save method?

Comment: Updated the code in the question, thanks

Comment: @Uerschel did you have a thought on what could be wrong?

Comment: Taking too long to create a reproducible environment here's something to get you started https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QOQoOHmUhmrzNbAW you can use it to create a reproducible example then add that to your question.

Comment: Thanks @RBee i have updated it to work and reproduce the issue https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mEweYHwBwqNxAnJi

Comment: here you can see i have added the required attributes and it works on the template name but not on the customer name https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GEGSkxGrGBqyVXZR

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here.  Your `CustomerComponent` just appears to change the value of `Template.Customer.Name`.  Your mutating the existing object, not changing the actual object.  `CustomerComponent` should probably be a custom Input control with proper binding, but I don't have a solid enough handle on the use case to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that the child component validation is captured in the parent component's `EditForm` you can use `EditContext.OnValidationRequested`, where you pass the `EditContext` from the parent component to the child component as a `CascadingParameter`.

> **NOTE**: i've used a `@bind-Customer` here

```js
// CustomerTemplateComponent.razor
<EditForm Model="@Template" OnValidSubmit="SaveEvent" Context="EditContext">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
    <br />
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 6px;">
        <div class="col-12">
            <MudTextField id="TemplateName" For="@(() => Template.TemplateName)" @bind-Value="Template.TemplateName" 
                            Label="Template Name:" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Margin="Margin.Dense">
                </MudTextField>
        </div>
    </div>
    <CascadingValue Value="EditContext">
        <CustomerComponent CustomerList="@CustomerList" @bind-Customer="@Template.Customer"/>
    </CascadingValue>
    
    <div class="row" style="padding-top:8px;">
        <div class="col-12 text-end mb-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" disabled="@Processing" id="Save-Button">Save</button>
            <div type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="CancelEvent" id="Cancel-Button">Cancel</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool Processing { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Template Template { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback CancelEvent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback SaveEvent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public IEnumerable<string> CustomerList { get; set; }

    private EditContext EditContext;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        EditContext = new EditContext(Template);
    }
}
```

Then, in the child component i.e. `CustomerComponent`. We subscribe to the `EditContext.OnValidationRequested` event which will be triggered when the form requests validation i.e. when submit button is clicked. Here we can use this event to validate the property and then `EditContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged` to propagate the validation back to the parent components `EditContext`.

Some other changes made :

- Change `@bind-Value` to using `Value` & `ValueChanged` as we need to implement custom logic when the `MudAutoComplete`'s value changes, and this allows us to use `@bind-Customer` on the parent component.
- `ValidationMessageStore` - This is used to hold validation messages and is tied to the EditContext when instantiated i.e. `new ValidationMessageStore(ParentEditContext);`

```js
// CustomerComponent.razor
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@implements IDisposable

<div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
    <div class="col-4 mb-3">
        <MudAutocomplete id="name" T="string" Label="Name:"
            Value="@Customer.Name" ResetValueOnEmptyText="true"
            ValueChanged="@HandleNameChanged" SearchFunc="@SearchCustomer" 
            For="@(() => Customer.Name)"
            Margin="Margin.Dense" Dense="true" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] public EditContext ParentEditContext { get; set; }
    private ValidationMessageStore _messageStore;

    [Parameter] public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<Customer> CustomerChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public IEnumerable<string> CustomerList { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (ParentEditContext != null)
        {
            _messageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(ParentEditContext);

            ParentEditContext.OnValidationRequested += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                _messageStore.Clear();
                Validate();
                ParentEditContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
            };
        }
    }

    async Task HandleNameChanged(string newName)
    {
        Customer.Name = newName;
        await CustomerChanged.InvokeAsync(Customer);
    }

    void Validate()
    {
        var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var context = new ValidationContext(Customer)
        {
            MemberName = nameof(Customer.Name)
        };

        Validator.TryValidateProperty(Customer.Name, context, validationResults);

        foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
        {
            _messageStore.Add(new FieldIdentifier(Customer, nameof(Customer.Name)), validationResult.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (ParentEditContext != null)
        {
            ParentEditContext.OnValidationRequested -= (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                _messageStore.Clear();
                Validate();
                ParentEditContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
            };
        }
    }

    private Task<IEnumerable<string>> SearchCustomer(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            Customer.Name = "";
            return Task.FromResult(CustomerList.AsEnumerable());
        }
        var filteredList = CustomerList.Where(x => x.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        return Task.FromResult(filteredList.AsEnumerable());
    }
}
```

Demo [MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QkmyERmBhAQckfNW)

If you want to re-validate the entire object instead of just one property then you can use `Validator.TryValidateObject`. I've included that snippet in the demo.

```js
void ValidateEntireObject()
{
    var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
    Validator.TryValidateObject(Customer, new ValidationContext(Customer), validationResults, true);

    foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
    {
        _messageStore.Add(new FieldIdentifier(Customer, validationResult.MemberNames.First()), validationResult.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```